# Clicking HTML form submit button calls a function. Will function always complete before form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML form. One of the form fields values is set by a JavaScript function. The JavaScript function is called when the submit button is clicked. Can I be sure that the function always finishes in time and sets the field value before the form is submitted?

EDIT: here's the code, as requested.

```
        $('#submitbutton').click(function () {
            createWholeArray();
        });

        function createWholeArray() {

            var templateString = width + " " + height + "\n";

            for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    if ($('#' + x + '-' + y).hasClass('selected')) {
                        templateString = templateString.concat("\n" + x + " " + y);
                    }
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('templatestring').value = templateString;
        }
```

Comment: How are you intercepting the submission? Show us a little code :)

Comment: no, you cannot be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing.
Change the submit button to normal Button and put click event to him.

by clicking on normal button manually submit your page.
i have done same in my project following is code for that.

```
$("#SignUpButton").click(function()
        {
                $('#loginForm').attr('method','post');
                $('#loginForm').attr('action','SignupServlet');
                $('#loginForm').submit();
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, the `submit` event gets fired before the actual submit (which causes a reload of the page) is done. You can even prevent the form to be sent with your script. Please note that you can only be sure, if you want your action to be done before the browsers default form sending is done.

This is in fact only the case if you use synchron actions only in that function. If you use asynchronous functions, you have to prevent the form to be submitted now and submit it from the callback of that function.

Please be aware of using the `submit` event on the form instead of a `click` event on your button (if appropriate). It'll make sure, that your function is also called when the form is sent by hitting enter or other possibilities to send the form.

As MarkP has pointed out in the comments, keep in mind that it is possible, that the user has javascript disabled, which can lead to unexpected results in your case.

Comment: @manta If there is no javascript already handling the form, so we are talking about just the default browser behaviour, using the submit event will do what he expects it to do (setting the value of an input field to something).

Comment: If the user's browser has JavaScript disabled the function will not fire but the submit event will (assuming this is set in the <form> tag.

Comment: @MarkP fair point, i was assuming that javascript is enabled, since the function won't do anything at all without it, but it's worth mentioning to keep that in mind!